# Set Additional Data to highcharts series in Area Chart with Line

Tags: highcharts

I can't seem to figure out how to add an additional data point to the series data in Highcharts when running an area chart with line.

Here's the chart that I'd like to add an additional data point to:
http://jsfiddle.net/localman/uL8rwu6f/

```
$(function () {

var ranges = [
        [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
        [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
        [1246579200000, 15.5, 29.6]
    ],
    averages = [
        [1246406400000, 21.5],
        [1246492800000, 22.1],
        [1246579200000, 23]
    ];


$('#container').highcharts({

    title: {
        text: 'July temperatures'
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },

    legend: {
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: averages,
        zIndex: 1,
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'white',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Range',
        data: ranges,
        type: 'arearange',
        lineWidth: 0,
        linkedTo: ':previous',
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        zIndex: 0
    }]
});
```

});

I can display the additional data in a single series, but not with the above for some reason http://jsfiddle.net/localman/dWDE6/859/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},

tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        return 'Extra data: <b>' + this.point.myData + '</b>';
    }
},

series: [{
    name: 'Foo',
    data: [{
        y: 3,
        myData: 'firstPoint'
    }, {
        y: 7,
        myData: 'secondPoint'
    }, {
        y: 1,
        myData: 'thirdPoint'
    }]
}]
```

});

Any suggestions on how to combine these?

Comment: I am not sure what you would like to achieve. Do you want to add real points to your chart? Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/uL8rwu6f/1/ Or maybe you want to add additional information to your tooltip?

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/uL8rwu6f/2/).

Comment: No idea what you mean. You add another point by adding another array element to the data array. What, specifically, are you trying to do, and what about it is not working?